# ListLinePlot/ListPlot: How to center the ticks on the steps in the plot?

Tags: plotting

I am plotting xy-data using ListLinePlot with option `InterpolationOrder->0` to get a step-like output. Now, the ticks are aligned to the rising part of the step (or vice versa), but I would like to have the ticks *centered* on the flat part of the step.

Same is true got ListPlot with option `Joined->True`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ListStepPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListStepPlot.html) with `"Center"` as the second argument:

```
data={{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 8}, {8, 16}, {13, 32}, {21,64}};
ListStepPlot[data, "Center", PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]